# Is it necessary to caulk between bathtub and drywall?

Tags: drywall, bathtub, caulk

Our house was built in 2017. It was not built to the... *highest* quality standards. One thing I have wondered since shortly after we moved in is this:

Should the builder have caulked where the tub/shower meets the drywall?

[image]

I don't know a ton about how the tub and wall area is constructed. My initial presumption is that any little splash would be seeping under the crack and potentially getting soaked up into the drywall or into the wood behind it that I presume the tub is attached to, and that this was an oversight by the builder.

On the other hand, I wonder if it's intentional. Perhaps it was left uncaulked to allow for water to air out?

Googling leads me to believe that most people *do* caulk it. Just wanting some confirmation before I do the work.

Edit:

Here's a zoomed-out view for context. There is a 'tray' around the tub. But splashes do still happen on occasion above that tray.

[image]

The shower is a similar story:

[image]

Again, I am not an expert by any stretch. I *presume* that this is tub/shower meeting drywall with regular paint, which seems bad to me. But it's possible it is something hardier and/or it's possible it's got some more water-resistant paint.

This happened a little while back over the shower enclosure, which is a little short in my opinion; some spray gets on top of the shower pretty regularly.

[image]

I don't know if the peeling layer is joint tape, a hard layer of a special water-resistant paint, some water-resistant layer of something not-drywall... or if this is the drywall just coming apart.

I know I need to repair it regardless. I've been hesitant because it's on a wet wall -- in fact, it's right under the shower nozzle (hence why it got wet). I don't know if I can just peel this layer back and repair it, or if I need to stick a drywall saw through the wall and carefully cut it out and patch it with something, or if I should think about replacing it with tiling or what.

Definitely out of my depth here. Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: Can we see a shot of a wider area? Is that really simple drywall used as a shower back-board? If it is, I'm surprised it's looking so good after 4 years. I'd suspect it's something slightly more hardy/water-resistant. I'd still have caulked it, based on that single image. You don't leave gaps where water runs down to 'let it air', they have a tendency to instead 'get very wet'.

Comment: I'm shocked it isn't blue board or cement board.  And, that it isn't tiled.

Comment: This is going to cause water leakage every time someone takes a shower...

Comment: Press your fingers along the bottom edge.  If it is hard then you can use caulk to seal.  If your fingers are able to push in/ the wall is spongy, then more work needs to be done.  Replacement of part of the wall.

Comment: A layer or 2 of 'interior' grade paint over drywall is not going to last very long in a shower. I predict it won't be very long until the entire wall soaks up water and turns to mush. That un-caulked gap makes it worse - but caulking the gap is not going to fix the long-term problem. There's a reason that even low-budget shower inserts are made of solid sheets of plastic...

Comment: Is that the top of the shower wall, which would be above the spray? (That’s the only place it makes sense to see fiberglass meeting drywall in a horizontal seam.)

Comment: @TimB - looks more like just the top lip of a shower tray to me - hence my earlier request for clarification. If it is, then I'd hate to live underneath ;)

Comment: My previous house, built in 1989, used green board around the shower and tub, with tile on top of the greenboard.  I had to replace the greenboard in the shower with cement board as water got in behind the tiles (around the shower fixtures) and caused the greenboard to fall apart.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Extra pics added. I think you're right; I'm guessing it's water-resistant drywall perhaps?

SteveSh: Yeah, no tiling.

bobflux: That was my thinking. :/

crip659: I pushed all along on both bath and shower. In the middle around the tub, it's starting to peel like the pic of the shower.